# lstlisting line wrapping

Tags: listings, sourcecode

How is it possible to let `lstlisting` wrap lines?

I've troubles with following block:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java] 
public class MeasureStationControllerV0Test {   
MeasureStationControllerV0 controller;  
MeasureStation ms = new MeasureStation();   
MeasureStationConfiguration config = new MeasureStationConfiguration();     
DataServer dataserver = new DataServer();
```

In the PDF output there is an overflow:

[image: overlapping code]

Other code-snippets look horrible too.

- So have I to manually wrap them or is `listings` able to handle that?
- Why isn't syntax highlighting working?

Comment: add `breaklines=true` to the options of the `lstlisting` environment

Comment: breaklines=true worked for me, but either it doesn't look nice. howerver, can you post als answer so i can accept?

Comment: For your second question (Why does Syntax hilightening isn't working?) we'd need to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and explain what's wring. My guess would be that you have to define additional keywords.

Comment: @cgnieder I am curious on how do we define additional keywords.  In my case, as is never highlighted when I use this package with Python.

Comment: @clemens That's what I needed! Thanks you so much! I spent an hour trying to fix this...

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use the options `breaklines=true` and `postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}` for placing a red arrow at the beginning of the broken line to emphasize the line break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}  % for bold teletype font
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \hookrightarrow
\usepackage{xcolor}   % for \textcolor
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java]
public class MeasureStationControllerV0Test {   
        MeasureStationControllerV0 controller;  
        MeasureStation ms = new MeasureStation();   
        MeasureStationConfiguration config = new MeasureStationConfiguration();     
        DataServer dataserver = new DataServer();
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With the `minted` package you get nice line breaking and syntax highlighting out-of-the-box.  Simply specify the `breaklines` option on your snippet.  The downside is that you have to process the document with the `--shell-escape` option because the external program `pygmentize` is used to format the source code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % for bold teletype font
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines,frame=single]{java}
public class MeasureStationControllerV0Test {   
        MeasureStationControllerV0 controller;  
        MeasureStation ms = new MeasureStation();   
        MeasureStationConfiguration config = new MeasureStationConfiguration();     
        DataServer dataserver = new DataServer();
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer from @henri-menke, besides the option `breaklines=true` and a postbreak arrow, I find it useful to make the arrow non-selectable in text (works for pdflatex and most pdf readers).
This advice comes from another answer using `accsupp` package: [Is there a way to make a "non-selectable" space in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158884/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-non-selectable-space-in-latex)

To summarize the solution:

```
\usepackage{accsupp}
% ...
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\ensuremath{\color{gray}\hookrightarrow\space}\EndAccSupp{}},
  breaklines=true
}
```

A typical arrow could be `\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{gray}\hookrightarrow\space}}`, but in this case, we put it between `\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}` and `\EndAccSupp{}`, so that its symbol becomes non-existent for copy and paste.

Comment: I assume this is to make it possible to copy-paste code from the PDF. Unfortunately this is of very limited usefulness, because the PDF does not preserve indentation which is crucial in some programming languages and extra precautions have to be taken to treat some special characters like `'` correctly.

Comment: That's true @HenriMenke , my use-case was for C#, which can survive the loss of indenting... but for python or haskell, that would be fatal. I couldn't find a better solution to keep indent, as my editors refuse to keep it, even when replacing space chars with other non-visible alternatives... maybe replace with a special symbol (such as §) and then replace it manually, could be a possibility.