# Adjusting the text width of R listings in LaTex

Tags: listings, r, width, text, lstdefinestyle

Hi I have `R` codes that I am listing in my LaTex file with

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]

R code

\end{lstlisting}
```

I have no specific listing setting in my preamble.
My `R` code is very wide and falls of the pages on the right side of the PDF file. How can I make sure that the width is the same as the text width of the whole file?

thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116534/lstlisting-line-wrapping

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lstlisting line wrapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116534/lstlisting-line-wrapping)